# jQuery tablesorter plugin styling

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tablesorter

I have [this page](http://www.studioteknik.com/html/googleapi/test.html) and the jquery function doesn't seem to execute.

It should work like the example in [this page](http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Credits).

Any idea of what go wrong?

Comment: Can you be more specific on what doesn't work? The sorting seems to be working ok to me in Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery function is working fine. Looks like you missed applying styles to your table.

```
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
```